# Get content uri of an audio file from its absolute path

Tags: android, mediastore

I have gone through a lot of stackoverflow questions but I couldn't find an answer to this. There is an answer for Image files but that doesn't work in my case.

So I have the absolute path of the file using `file.getAbsolutePath()`. But I need to convert it to contentUri so that below query works fine.

```
Cursor tempCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    proj, null, null, null);
```

It is not working. I tried `Uri.parse(contentUri)` but that doesn't give the content uri I guess. Please help me, I am stuck since a long time. Thanks !!

Comment: "But I need to convert it to contentUri so that below query works fine" -- why? What is in the query results that you are expecting, that you cannot get from the file? Bear in mind that the `MediaStore` does not know about, or even have access to, all files.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot for the reply. I need to get song ID from the file path. That is why I need to execute the query.

Comment: "I need to get song ID from the file path" -- why? What value does the song ID have?

Comment: Its a long I guess. I need song ID because my app  has various options which depend on the song ID like playing the song, etc etc.

Comment: Then either do not use files, or make your model more flexible, so that it can handle streams from `MediaStore` *or* local files.

Comment: I have to use files at only one place, where I display the folder structure of the user's SD card/ internal memory so that he/she can play songs from there. At other places this wasn't the case. But I am not sure I can avoid it here?

Answer (score 3):

You do not use the get.absolute etc. Simply query the Medfiastore.Audio etc  and bring back _id and _DATA. _id is the song id and _DATA has the full path and track

below a piece of code which you could use. Just feed it the track name

```
    public String getThisTrackId(Context context, String trackName) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    final String[] columns = { _id };
    final String[] trackname = { "%"+ trackName +"%" };
    String where = path + " LIKE ?";
    String strtrack_id  = null;
    Cursor crs =cr.query(uri, columns, where, trackname, null);
    if(crs!= null && crs.moveToFirst()){
        strtrack_id  = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_id));
        crs.close();
    }

    return strtrack_id;
}
```

Comment: Varunkr, did any of my posts help you solve your issue?. If so can you accept as answer and perhaps even vote it up?

Comment: .DATA was deprecated in Android 10. For android 11 the manuals talk about .data again so perhaps it is back. IMHO a bad decision from google to do away with the full path. Why?